# redirect with asp.net mvc for routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

I'm new to MVC, so please help me out here.
I need to redirect `myhost.com/contactus` to `myhost.com/aController/aView`.

I tried

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "contactus",
            url: "contactus",
            defaults: new { controller = "aController", action = "aView"}
        );
```

but no luck. What am I missing :(

Comment: remove `/{id}` - you don't need the id there.

Comment: Or set `id = UrlParameter.Optional` if you want to exclude `id` parameter.

Comment: I got id removed, I just want to redirect from /contactus  to  /aController/aView

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "contactus",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "aController", action = "aView", id = UrlParameter.Optional },

        );
```